# TypeScript Compiler API: from string to AST

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Is it possible to convert a string of TypeScript code snippet to AST node? In memory, without creating any a file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, use the [`ts.createSourceFile`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/4e25aedb7b89d02c6606ed354c6e42378d69c143/lib/typescript.d.ts#L3830) function:

```
import * as ts from "typescript";

const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(
    "file.ts",                  // filePath
    "function myFunction() {}", // fileText
    ts.ScriptTarget.Latest,     // scriptTarget
    true                        // setParentNodes -- sets the `parent` property
);
```

Comment: I saw codes like this online but thought this would create a file 'file.ts'. After testing it locally I found this didn't create any file. The filePath parameter confused me, but it works now. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it won't create a file on the file system. It's used to set the `SourceFile#fileName` property and to help determine the `ts.ScriptKind` (which is the last optional parameter on this function).